# Hibernate projections with collections ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, hibernate

Hello guys I have this code:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Department.class);

ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
properties.add(Projections.property("id"), "id");
properties.add(Projections.property("name"), "name");
properties.add(Projections.property("children"), "children");

criteria.setProjection(properties);
criteria.setFetchMode("children", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Department.class));

criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("parent.id"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("active", true));

return criteria.list();
```

and entity class

```
public class Department extends Model {

    @Size(max = 200)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 10)
    private String sg;

    @Size(max = 1000)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent")
    private Department parent;

    private boolean active;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Department> children;
```

... plus getters and setters...

I execute the criteria and give me the stacktrace exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultRow(CriteriaLoader.java:166)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CriteriaLoader.java:146)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:747)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:949)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:917)
at
```

What am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code to "execute the criteria" and the stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing what you are trying to do with that Projection query, it's hard to say how to fix it.  I think your main problem is that you need to create an alias to the children and then use that alias in your projection.  In your projection, you'd also need to reference properties of children.  You could do this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Department.class);

ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
properties.add(Projections.property("id"), "id");
properties.add(Projections.property("name"), "name");
properties.add(Projections.property("children.id"), "id");
properties.add(Projections.property("children.name"), "name");

criteria.setProjection(properties);
criteria.createAlias("children",  "children", JoinType.FULL_JOIN);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Department.class));

criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("parent.id"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("active", true));
return criteria.list();
```

That said, I think using a Projection here is a mistake and unnecessary if your intent is to return a list of root Departments with their children Department trees.  For that, you could just do this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Department.class);
criteria.createAlias("children",  "children", JoinType.FULL_JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("parent.id"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("active", true));

retun criteria.list();
```

Comment: Thanks, i using the projections because i need only certain fields, thanks for reply!! I go try your solution!

Comment: Are you trying to save bandwidth?  Even if you don't need all the fields, you will be better off just querying the entity instead using a Hibernate projection.  aliasToBean transformer does not map child relationships. There's a custom transformer on github for this but it does not work with one-to-many, only one-to-one and many-to-one: https://github.com/samiandoni/AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer